# Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Prove that if $G = HK$, then for any $x, y \in G$ $xH \cap yK \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's easy to show that if $G = HK$, $HK = KH$. Thus $xH = kH$ for some $k \in K$ and $yK = hK$ for some $h \in H$. So the question is narrowed to proving that $kH \cap hK \neq \emptyset$. Unfortunately, I can't go any further.

Comment: You haven't yet used the hypothesis that $H,K$ have finite index in $G$.

Comment: @Shaun: you appear to know more about the question than the OP (who has not stated that hypothesis).

Comment: See [the original version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4043794/1), @RobArthan.

Comment: @Shaun: I see. I should have looked at the edit history. That hypothesis isn't actually relevant.

Comment: @Shaun, sorry, I had to edit the topic. I wanted to see the proof without using this fact but I was uncertain if it is possible so I originally put it but then decided to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: you are very close. If $G = HK$, then $G$ is the union of the cosets $hK$ for $h\in H$, so any coset $zK$ is $hK$ for some $h \in H$. But then $xH \cap yK = x(H \cap (x^{-1}y)K) = x(H \cap h K)$ for some $h \in H$ and so, as $h = he \in H \cap hK$, we have $xh \in xH \cap yK$. So $xH \cap yK \neq \emptyset$

Comment: Thank you! It turned out to be so simple.